# Why were my comments removed?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I visited this question: [order elements with function sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55437113/6699433)

First, I commented "SO is not a code writing service". The OP responded with "I have my function I just don't know how to plug it here with the correct indention." to which I replied "Just paste it. I can probably fix it."

Both these comments were removed pretty quickly. Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a question or answer within the last year referencing the decision years ago to [remove the "What Stack Overflow is not" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137795/363946), basically suggesting that saying what SO is not is unhelpful, and that such comments should be removed. I can't find the reference so I can't tell you if there was a community consensus on the matter, but I do agree that such comments don't hold much value and are more likely to upset the OP rather than actually help them improve their question.

Comment: Don't waste your time attempting to squeeze blood out of stones, AKA trying to prod askers into fixing their bad questions; downvote and move on to something that's actually answerable. If they want good answers, they can damn well take the time to read the help center and post good questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, your first comment there was:

> SO is not a code writing service
> – Broman 2 hours ago

That one was flagged as "unfriendly or unkind". I declined the flag because I (subjectively) did not agree that the comment really rose to the level of "unfriendly or unkind", but at the same time, I didn't really think it was a useful comment, so I deleted it.

No, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but you can often ask questions in such a way that people will help you write code. The distinction is often lost on people, and your comment didn't help to clarify. Rather than being "unfriendly or unkind", it was what I would prefer to call *unconstructive*.

A *useful* comment might have still made the same observation regarding the nature of Stack Overflow, but would also have explained how the question could be materially improved to make it fit within Stack Overflow's guidelines.

Without offering that advice, it was more of a "go away" comment. "Go away" comments shouldn't be posted; use close votes for that.

The next two comments were:

> I have my function I just don't know how to plug it here with the correct indention
> – Matilde Pinheiro 2 hours ago
>
> Just paste it. I can probably fix it.
> – Broman 2 hours ago

I closed the question (it should have been closed *anyway*, but it *especially* needed closing with the asker's admission that he had code he was unable to share with us, since at such time as he figured out how to share it with us, any answers that the question might have received in the meantime would have surely been invalidated). Then, I deleted your second comment.

That one wasn't flagged. I just decided on my own that it was not useful. Frankly, it's terrible advice. Please don't advise people to post garbage—things they *know* are unreadable—and expect others to fix it. I appreciate that you are willing to fix it, but that's not the way we want to encourage folks to use this website.

I instead replaced it with what I consider to be a more useful comment: a pointer to our formatting help. This will allow the asker to figure out how to format his code himself, thus educating him, saving you a tiny bit of work, and a saving bunch of future editors (and reviewers) each a tiny bit of work.

---

In summary, please don't read too much into this. If there was a real problem, someone would have contacted you. This was just run-of-the-mill cleanup by a moderator that just happened to be initiated by a flag.

I'm not even sure why you're asking this question. Were you really so attached to those comments that you're uncomfortable with their deletion? Don't be.

By the way, I *also* just deleted your comment there pinging me with a link to this Meta question, since it's obsolete and irrelevant to the question it was attached to. *Three deleted comments!* (No, that's not anywhere close to a record.)